# Como passar uma variável local para uma classe anônima?

Tags: java, escopo-de-variáveis

Preciso passar a variável de controle de um `for`, como parâmetro para um método. O problema, é que eu estou tentando fazer isso de acordo com o `JRadioButton` que foi selecionado, eu estou criando eles de acordo com o meu for, e definido eventos para eles em seguida.

A questão, é que dentro do `ActionEvent` não posso usar a variável de controle do for, a menos que ela seja final, porém, isso não é possível, já que ela pode mudar de "tamanho" conforme as colunas de uma tabela.

(Observação: no `if`, em `e.getActionCommand().equals(tituloColuna[i])` é uma tentativa de fazer com que a ação seja aplicada apenas para o `radioButton` que tenha o mesmo nome que o dá condição).

Alguém tem alguma sugestão ?

Fiz um exemplo bem simples, apenas para ilustrar a situação.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TesteFor extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {
            TesteFor ts = new TesteFor();
            ts.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public TesteFor() {
        setTitle("Teste");
        add(componentesTela());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(375, 300));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent componentesTela() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        String tituloColuna[] = {"Coluna 01", "Coluna 02"};

        //Tabela apenas para indicar de onde veio os valores, não estou adicionando ela no exemplo.
        JTable tabela = new JTable();
        tabela.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "", ""
                }
        ));

        int numeroColunas = tabela.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < numeroColunas; i++) {
            JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("Ocultar " + tituloColuna[i]);
            jp.add(radio);
            radio.setActionCommand(tituloColuna[i]); //e.getActionCommand() vai retornar o nome do radio clicado

            radio.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)
                    -> {
                //ERRO
                /*if (e.getActionCommand().equals(tituloColuna[i])) {
                    alterarTabela(i);
                    System.out.println("Peguei a " + e.getActionCommand());
                }*/
            });
        }
        return jp;
    }

    private void alterarTabela(int indiceColuna) {
        //alterar colunas de acordo com o indice.
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que não transforma a variavel em campo de classe?

Comment: @diegofm como assim ?

Comment: Não entendi nada do que está sendo feita nesse laço. Pode explicar melhor? Tem um array de colunas que nunca é relacionado a uma tabela, que tambem nunca é utilizada no código.

Comment: @diegofm posso sim! Vamos lá, então o for vai ser feito enquanto ele for menor que o numeroColunas, que eu estou pegando da tabela. Depois eu crio os radios de acordo a essa quantidade de colunas, e por fim dou o nome das colunas para eles com o tituloColuna, nesse exemplo não fica claro a utilidade do array com os nomes, mais é porque eu não achei necessário adiciona-los dinamicamente ai, e nem a tabela, que eu so coloquei para pegar as colunas.

Comment: Mas ai você gera um problema de interpretação do que o código realmente vai fazer, e fica complicado sugerir alguma forma até relacionado no swing, que seja mais facil ou melhor talvez que essa que está fazendo.

Comment: Você realmente cria um array pra nomes de colunas na sua aplicação? Se a resposta é não, da pra fazer diferente disso ai.

Comment: @diegofm sim eu crio, e adicionado em um outro momento. Ai ele esta pegando o array apenas para dar o nome dos radios.

Comment: O código não está fazendo muito sentido pra mim. Na mesma iteração, você adiciona um actioncommand no radiobutton e depois faz um if pra checar se é ele mesmo, não faz sentido isso.

Comment: É que eu precisava tentar fazer algo para não executar os demais radios juntos, mais se tiver alguma sugestão eu posso tentar mudar.

Comment: Mas pra que você define um actioncommand e depois verifica se é ele mesmo dentro do mesmo radio que acabou de defini-lo? Percebe a redundancia do seu código? Esse if é completamente desnecessário.

Comment: @diegofm realmente, confirmei isso agora, não é mesmo necessário. Agora eu preciso resolver a variável dentro do evento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas formas de se resolver esse problema de escopo: ou você arruma uma forma de passar uma variável local final pra classe anônima ou aumenta o escopo da variável a nível de classe. Creio que a segunda opção não seja tão útil, uma vez que você aparentemente só vai usar essa variável pra iterar o laço e mais nada.

Também é possível contornar isso criando uma classe que estenda o listener que você quer aplicar, passando o valor para essa nova classe, mas acredito que também não seja necessário aumentar a complexidade a esse nível de acordo com o exemplo dado.

Então podemos resolver com a primeira forma, que é criar um jeito de passar o índice da iteração do laço a classe anônima, de forma que a iteração possa ser incrementada e a variável de iteração do laço não necessite ser final. Para isso, basta fazer uma cópia do índice atual dentro do laço e passar essa cópia pra classe anônima, pois ela poderá ser final, já que só nos importa seu valor até o final da iteração corrente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeroColunas; i++) {
    JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("Ocultar " + tituloColuna[i]);
    jp.add(radio);
    radio.setActionCommand(tituloColuna[i]); //e.getActionCommand() vai retornar o nome do radio clicado
    final int currentIndex = i;
    radio.addActionListener(e -> {
            alterarTabela(currentIndex);
            System.out.println("Peguei a " + e.getActionCommand());
    });
}
```

Dessa forma, as alterações no seu código são mínimas, resolvendo o problema do escopo.

Dentro do exemplo dado na pergunta, essa é a sugestão menos trabalhosa e que menos vai alterar o seu código.